# Replace characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
"vtn:o:result:/buffer/get/"
```

I want to replace character "o" with "b"
So that resultant string is

```
"vtn:b:result:/buffer/get/"
```

I am trying following method:

```
var alphabet = "vtn:o:result:/buffer/get/";
alphabet = alphabet.replace(/:o.*:/, 'b');
```

But not getting the required result. I don't want to use jQuery, just JavaScript.

Comment: Why not just `= alphabet.replace(':o:', ':b:');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
 alphabet.replace('o', 'b');
```

Comment: It will replace every o in string. I am assuming that /buffer/get/ can be /boffer/get, then this o will also be replaced i want to replace only o which are in between two colons

Comment: replace(':o:', ':b:');

Comment: @VarunChadha: No, it won't replace every `o` in the string, it will only replace the first.

Comment: if i have string "von:o:result:/buffer/get/", then resultant string will be "vbn:o:result:/buffer/get/", which is not expected